# [Sharepoint Designer]Erro ao tentar estabelecer conexão com serviço web - "O servidor não pode concluir a sua solicitação"

Tags: iis, sharepoint

Olá,

Estou tentando realizar conexão com os sites presentes no meu servidor pelo Sharepoint e não consigo de forma nenhuma.

Ao tentar abrir a solução, recebo o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao clicar em Detalhes, vejo uma caixa de texto vazia e após dar OK nessa página aparece o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei seguir a seguinte dica: brightworksupport.com/error-when-opening-site-in-sharepoint-designer-2013/

Porém nada aconteceu, retirei a autenticação por formulário após um teste, pois o próprio servidor reclamava de conflito, porém continuei sem sucesso.

Ao tentar abrir a o sharepoint designer pela execução Web ele abre um txt e mostra uma janela de erro de conexão com a internet

Alguem consegue me ajudar? =/

Comment: Segue link, que pode ser útil. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/ccf00a2c-2ef6-4447-90ed-65261a41396b/editar-o-sharepoint-com-sharepoint-designer-como-habilitar?forum=sharepointpt Veja a ultima parte, habilitar na central admin.

Comment: Eu já havia feito essa liberação anteriormente. Obrigado, Leandro!

Comment: Verifique se o Pool ou o site do Sharepoint Web Services Root está parado no IIS Manager do Servidor que deseja recuperar informações, pode ser esta a causa.